# Crop an Image (Enhanced Metafile) in PPT 2007

Tags: vba, image-processing, powerpoint, crop

Can anyone help me with an issue in PPT 2007.

I have an image (a chart from excel pasted as 'Picture (Enhanced Metafile)') in a slide. I just need to crop this image to fit in the slide. I tried following code, but to no avail:

'1:

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)

```
    .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 10

    .PictureFormat.CropTop = 10

    .PictureFormat.CropRight = 10

    .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 10

End With

'Runtime error "ActiveX Component can't create object
```

'2:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.CropRight = 10

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.CropLeft = 10

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.CropBottom = 10

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.PictureFormat.CropTop = 10

'Object doesnt support this property or method
```

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: I've tested using a chart from Excel 2010 pasting as an EMF in PowerPoint 2010 and your code is working just fine. Maybe you're not pasting as an EMF or you've not designated the right object? Try on a slide with no other shapes on it, only your .EMF chart.

Comment: Yes, the code works when there is no other objects in the slide. But, in this case there are many other objects and images. How do I differentiate between these? The selection method pasted above does not work...

Answer (score 0):

This works with EMFs pasted from Excel:

```
  Dim oSh as Shape
  Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
  ' Note:  ShapeRange(1), not just ShapeRange
  '  That's the problem with your second example

  With oSh
     .CropLeft = 10
     ' etc
  End With
```

The fact that it's yelling about an activex object in the first example makes me wonder whether the first shape is really an EMF, which would not be an ActiveX object.